# MongoDB: efficient way to join collections inside a facet

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have an aggregation that can be summarized in:

```
db.getCollection('originalCollection').aggregate([
    $match: { //some filters }
    $project: { //some transformations}
    $facet: {
        "collectionA": [ //some transformation steps ],
        "collectionB": [ //some other transformation steps ]
    }
...
```

Now I want to make a SQL-like join with collections `A` and `B` using `id` field. For example, if I have this document in collection `A`:

```
{
    id: "A"
    property1: "a value"
}
```

and this document in collection `B`:

```
{
    id: "A"
    property2: "other value"
}
```

The resulting collection has to contain:

```
{
   id: "A",
   property1: "a value",
   property2: "other value"
}
```

I tried as next aggregation step to use a `$map` on collection `A` that uses a `$filter` to match a document with the same id in collection `B`, but is VERY slow:

```
{
    "$project": {
        "tmpResult": {
            "$map": {
                "input": "$collectionA",
                "as": "collectionADocument",
                "in": {
                    "property1": "$$collectionADocument.property1",
                    "property2": {
                        "$arrayElemAt": [
                            {
                                "$filter": {
                                    "input": "$collectionB",
                                    "cond": {
                                        "$eq": [
                                            "$$collectionADocument.id",
                                            "$$this.id"
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            0
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What is the fastest way to achieve the join in the two collections in the facet? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `$filter`s are very fast, share how many items has `collectionA` and `collectionB` arrays. Other solution could be `$concatArrays [collectionA, collectionB]` + `$unwind` + `$group` + `$mergeObjects`. You can make benchmarking to pick the best way...

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use $lookup, The $lookup operator added to the aggregation pipeline is essentially identical to a left outer join:

https://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#pipe._S_lookup

from the docs,

```
{
   $lookup:
     {
       from: <collection to join>,
       localField: <field from the input documents>,
       foreignField: <field from the documents of the "from" collection>,
       as: <output array field>
     }
}
```

For your example, it could be something like below,

```
db.B.aggregate({
   $lookup:
     {
       from: "A",
       localField: "id",
       foreignField: "id",
       as: "AB"
     }
})
```

Comment: Problem there is that I cannot have in a single aggregation. Then I have to delete collection A, B, etc.

Comment: So, You want a solution which has more then one aggregation pipelines..? And why do you have to delete collection A, B..? I don't understand your concern here.

Comment: I want a single aggregation for simplicity. If there are several aggregations then I have to delete intermediate collections like A and B because they are useless.